# Dagger not generating components for /test class

Tags: android, dagger-2

I am following the guide here: https://github.com/ecgreb/dagger-2-testing-demo

I have the following setup in my app/src/main (the injection and @Provides code omitted):

```
public class FlingyApplication extends Application {
    @Singleton
    @Component(modules = { FlingyModule.class })
    public interface FlingyComponent
}

@Module
public class FlingyModule
```

In app/src/test:

```
public class TestFlingyApplication extends Application {
    @Singleton
    @Component(modules = { TestFlingyModule.class })
    public interface TestFlingyComponent extends FlingyComponent
}

@Module
public class TestFlingyModule
```

So far, it is nearly identical to the example github. When dagger goes to generate the code for the Component builders in src/main, they generate properly. Dagger does not, however, generate code for the Component builders in src/test.

My main build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0-alpha3'

    classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.5.1'
}
```

My app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'


android {
    # There is obviously more in here, but this is the custom part:
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.8'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'

    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0.1'
    apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0.1'
    compile 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2'

    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.1.0'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.0'

    testCompile 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
}
```

So when I build, I get the `DaggerFlingyApplication_FlingyComponent` class, but not the `DaggerTestFlingyApplication_TestFlingyComponent`

Something interesting I noticed is that if I switch the line:

```
apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0.1'
# TO
compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0.1'
```

I see the following when I run `./gradlew compileDebugUnitTestSources`:

```
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
Note: /app/build/generated/source/apt/debug/com/jy/flingy/DaggerFlingyApplication_FlingyComponent.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
:app:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies
:app:compileDebugUnitTestJavaWithJavac
Note: /app/build/intermediates/classes/test/debug/com/jy/flingy/DaggerTestFlingyApplication_TestFlingyComponent.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
```

I don't know why it builds to intermediates and I assume that I need the build.gradle file to use `apt` instead of `compile`, but I can't seem to figure out how to get this to work. I know that it's absolutely possible.

Comment: This documentation (http://google.github.io/dagger/testing.html) advices not to use dagger for unit testing..

Comment: If you have a lot of dependencies, then it could point to your unit tests testing more than a single unit. That said, google doesn't always know best (gasp!) and that's a pretty broad statement by them. Using dagger in unit tests in particular cases works well for us, hence this question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60352086/4694013

Answer (score 144, accepted):

You need to add following to your `build.gradle` file for instrumentation test:

```
androidTestApt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:<version>'
```

or for JUnit test:

```
testApt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:<version>'
```

This is required to generate Dagger code for your test components.

---

**EDIT**:

If you are using `jack` tool chain then add following
for android test:

```
androidTestAnnotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:<version>'
```

for JUnit tests:

```
testAnnotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:<version>'
```

---

**EDIT**:

In case you are using `kotlin-kapt` for Kotlin code use following:

```
kaptAndroidTest 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:<version>'
```

or for JUnit test:

```
kaptTest 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:<version>'
```

Check [this](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kapt.html) link for more info.

Comment: Even if the tests are in /test, not /androidTest?

Comment: You are writing instrumentation test that should be in `androidTest`. If you are writing JUnit test then you can use `testApt`.

Comment: I get the following: ```Error:(55, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'testApt()'```

Comment: I had to upgrade apt to 1.7+... ```classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'``` to make testApt work

Comment: Thank you! I spent two days looking for the answer :)

Comment: I tried with this variant "testAnnotationProcessor" but the class is not being generated. Do you know if there is any issue with this approach?

Comment: This options is only available with `jack` tool chain.

Comment: The Jack processor dependencies do *not* work with processors in the /test directory. I switched to [apt](https://bitbucket.org/hvisser/android-apt) and it works fine. So if you need this functionality, ditch Jack and use apt.

Comment: Do you know if `testAnnotationProcessor` is supported for Kotlin? As far as I know just support `kapt`

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kapt.html This link says you can use `kaptTest` and `kaptAndroidTest` while using`kapt`.

Comment: Remember to execute the tests or run `assembleAndroidTest` to actually see the dependency class `DaggerMyComponent` resolved, simply `rebuild` will not generate the classes from dagger.

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful

Comment: Thank you sir. Very thorough and very helpful.

Comment: Saved me a lot of time. Thank you

Answer (score 36):

For Android Studio 3 and dagger 2.13 the already mentioned annotation processors are needed:

```
testAnnotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.13'
```

But also do not forgot to do this for the instrumented test under `androidTest`:

```
androidTestAnnotationProcessor'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.13'
```

You might get the impression that this alone does not work, because the DaggerXYZ classes are not generated. After hours I found out that the test source generation is only triggered when the tests are executed. If you start a `test` or `androidTest` from Android Studio the source generation should be triggered.

If you need this earlier trigger gradle manually:

```
gradlew <moduledirectory>:compile<Flavor>DebugAndroidTestSources
gradlew <moduledirectory>:compile<Flavor>DebugTestSources
```

Replace `Debug` if you run a test in a different build type.

**Note:**

If you are using multiDexEnable = true you might get an error:

> Test running failed: Instrumentation run failed due to
>   'java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError'

Use a different runner in this case:

```
android {

  defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner "com.android.test.runner.MultiDexTestRunner"
```

Comment: Yes you need to run some of the tests and then Dagger will generate the test dagger classes (components) +1

Comment: I've always thought that `rebuild` passes across the whole project, but obviously not. Thanks man.

Comment: androidTestAnnotationProcessor - that is what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 30):

Just to add a bit to the above answer, since there have been some recent changes.

From Android Gradle plugin version 2.2 and above you **will no longer use testApt**.

So from now on you need to put only this in the build.gradle:

```
testAnnotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:<version>'
```

But more than that, what I came here for, is the following: **if you need gradle to generate the DaggerComponent classes for you**  you will have to do a bit extra work.

Open our build.gradle file and AFTER the android section write this:

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    if (variant.buildType.name == "debug") {
        def aptOutputDir = new File(buildDir, "generated/source/apt/${variant.unitTestVariant.dirName}")
        variant.unitTestVariant.addJavaSourceFoldersToModel(aptOutputDir)
        assembleDebug.finalizedBy('assembleDebugUnitTest')
    }
}
```

This will create the directory build/generated/source/apt/test/ as a Java classes recipient and the last part will trigger the "assembleDebugUnitTest" task that will finally create those Dagger2 components in the folder that was just created.

Note that this script is just being triggered for the "debug" variant and takes advantage of that build variant using the "assembleDebug" task. If for some reason you need it in other variants just tweak that a bit.

Why Dagger2 does not do this automatically is beyond me, but hey, I am no pro.

Comment: Works for me, you've missed the ending `}`

Comment: I liked this approach because it doesn't require more android libraries to install. Because I am doing TDD in a separate library I started with android.libraryVariants.all

Comment: Fantastic. After searching for hours for an alternative to `testApt`, this did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: @saltandpepper any issues you are facing with the latest version of gradle?

Comment: Thank you. Took me 2 days to fix it. Kotlin + Dagger 2.19 + last gradle

Answer (score 18):

If you added kaptAndroidTest for dagger dependencies and still not getting test components when rebuild your project, try running assembleAndroidTest.

Comment: I recommend this answer because it helps you to look if there is something wrong with your dependency graph or other things out of dependencies

Comment: You saved my day bro, I was stuck in this issue for a long time.

Answer (score 3):

Adding to the above solution and adding the testKapt and androidTestKapt for dagger, I had the problem that my modules and components had the wrong imports as a result of missing imports

e.g

```
 import android.support.test.espresso.core.deps.dagger.Module
 import android.support.test.espresso.core.deps.dagger.Module
```

instead of

```
import dagger.Module
import dagger.Provides
```

Hope this helps

Comment: At first I skipped over this suggestion because I was sure it couldn't possibly be the problem, but after spending another 20min debugging I actually went and checked the imports. Lo and behold Android Studio had auto imported the espresso versions for some reason..

Comment: Solved the issue big brain

Answer (score 2):

Hi even after adding all gradle dependenices and annotations if it still doesnt work then you need to run assembleAndroidTest gradle script for this.
Simply make an empty test case and run it. It will do the job for you.
Cheers

Comment: OMG! I lost a lot of time by "build" option. but actually dagger files create by run even empty test.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using kotlin use "**kaptAndroidTest**" to generate dagger component for android tests in your build.gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

I ran `./gradlew build` from the command line and got information about a missing Provides method that Android Studio was not telling me about.