# How to generate DaggerComponent class in the test/java folder?

Tags: android, unit-testing, dagger-2

I'm new to Dagger 2 and I'm working on using Dagger 2 for unit tests. I would like to test my presenter and mock some of the datasources(Server connection, SharedPreferences).
For the SharedPreferences I have `SharedPreferencesComponent` in the `main` folder and `SharedPreferencesComponentFake` in the `test/java` folder. The problem is that dagger can't generate `DaggerSharedPreferencesComponentFake` therefore I can't inject `SharedPreferencesFake` instead the SharedPreferences.
How can i set up so dagger will generate the DaggerSharedPreferencesFake class , or am I using dagger 2 in the wrong way

Comment: Please try using the search function, since this seems like a question that has been asked before at least 3 times, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36231457/dagger-not-generating-components-for-test-class

Answer (score 0):

Why not use **Mockito** and just mock the **SharedPreferencesComponent**

```
  Mockito.when(SharedPreferencesComponent.yourMethod(any(String.class)))
            .thenReturn(yourWanterOutput);
```

This will make faking classes unnecessary and the code will be cleaner.

Comment: thats true, but i want to know is testing is better using dagger, i have already prepared fake clases

Comment: You use mocks and stubs in order to isolate behaviour. In this particular case, you don't want to test the shared preferences that is why you mock their behaviour so it is constant and not vital for the final result of the test. If you were about to test some real behaviour of the SharedPreferences then you can add them with the dagger. You can not say that dagger or mocking or stubbing is better for testing they all serve different purpose.