# Dagger 2 component not created in /test folder in an Android Kotlin project

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, dagger-2, android-studio-3.0

I have an Android Kotlin project that I write in Android Studio 3.

I want to use a Dagger 2 component (say TestComponent) for my unit tests in the /test folder.

After rebuilding the project, I see that the DaggerTestComponent is not created (When the dagger components in the /java folder are generated successfully)

I [read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38097727/876603) that this should be solved by adding

```
kaptTest "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$dagger_version"
```

but it does not work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you looked into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42796379/1083957)?

Comment: I changed generated/source/apt/ to generated/source/kapt/ and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Good! Seems like your questions is duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42793505/1083957). What do you think of removing it? Or do you want it to be answered?