# Dagger2 in kotlins's test never compiles

Tags: junit, kotlin, dagger-2

When i try to use `Dagger2` in `'/androidTest'` it compiles:

[image]

but for `/test` folder it fails:

[image]

I simplified code extremely, tried it accurate many times with variants but never succeeded

What a mystery knowledge i miss?

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems [i found the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38097727/2618498).

[image]