# annotationProcessor + androidTest + dagger2

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, dagger-2, android-instrumentation, annotation-processor

For instrumented tests, I have a `TestApplication` that creates a `TestComponent`, but the file is not generated anymore (`Error:/xxx/TestApplication.java:16: The import.xxx.DaggerTestApplicationComponent cannot be resolved`). I'm not able to identify the root cause. I've tried different Android Studio (2.2, 2.1.2), different gradle plugin (2.2.0-alpha6, 5, 4) and different versions of dagger (2.2 to 2.6).

Should I use `androidTestAnnotationProcessor`? (that was not the case before)

edit: to use dagger 2.6, need to add `classpath 'com.google.guava:guava:19.0'`

update: there was a problem with a `Module`, hence the `Component` couldn't be create. However, using jack (even with debug options), I couldn't see the problem. For now, reverting to java 7, gradle plugin 2.1.2. That way, no need to specify which guava version, and all the latest libs can be used (dagger 2.6, butterknife 8.2.1, apt 1.8)

Comment: did you try to generate it in the command line? there used to be an issue with dagger and test file generation, not sure if it is still the case

Comment: I haven't... But I suspect it started happening after enabling jack

Answer (score 19):

I had the same problem with Dagger 2.9. `compileDebugAndroidTestSources` was completing successfully but the `Dagger*Component` was not generated.

After struggling for about an hour I landed on this question and finally with some experiments found a solution:

Add

`androidTestAnnotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.9'`

and execute `compileDebugAndroidTestSources` again. Now sources should be generated (you may have to temporary comment out references to your `Dagger*Component` in order compilation to succeed) if your graph is OK.

If there is a problem with your graph (e.g. missing @Provides) now you will get an error (in contrast of the previous state without `androidTestAnnotationProcessor` where the task was completing without an error but sources were not generated)

`<rant>`

I used to love Dagger but every now and then there are some strange problems with it that make it a big risk for long commercial projects. Also they still don't have decent documentation for it which makes learning it by new developers very hard. Probably it is not just Dagger's fault, probably gradle and Android Studio have their part in the problems but I am seriously considering to dump it.

`</rant>`

Comment: If executing build, it will not work. Does task build call compileDebugAndroidTestSources?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the @Ognyan's answer, Keep in mind that `DaggerTestApplicationComponent` does not get generated until you build the test.

To build the test, open ActivityTest.kt, right-click on public class ActivityTest and choose `Run -> ActivityTest.kt`

[image]