# Dagger not see my own generated dependency

Tags: android, gradle, dagger-2, auto-generate, kapt

I have an issue with Dagger and my own generated code.

Assumptions:

1. I need to generate my own dagger component for UI tests purpose
2. I have my own Gradle's module for annotation processing which provides dagger component with dependencies. Call this `GeneratedTestCoreComponent`. This class is generated correctly
3. `GeneratedTestCoreComponent` is built at `\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\...`
4. `GeneratedTestCoreComponent` is used in dagger component, smth like this

```
@Component(modules = [UiTestModule::class],
    dependencies = [GeneratedTestCoreComponent::class])
interface TestUiComponent {}
```

5. My annotation processor module is correctly added to gradle

```
  implementation project(path: ':processor')
  kapt(name: 'processor')
```

The issue is. During compilation I get below error

```
TestUiComponent.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
@com.dagger.Component(modules = {com.xxx.xxx.UiTestModule.class}, dependencies = {GeneratedTestCoreComponent.class})

symbol: class GeneratedTestCoreComponent
TestUiComponent.java:8: error: [ComponentProcessor:MiscError] com.dagger.internal.codegen.ComponentProcessor was unable to process this interface because not all of its dependencies could be resolved. Check for compilation errors or a circular dependency with generated code.
public abstract interface TestUiComponent
```

Additional info.
When I copy `GeneratedTestCoreComponent` class from build directory to src (keeping the same package) and disable my processor, then everything works fine

Comment: are you using scopes for this ?

Comment: Have you tried with testImplementation and kaptTest to add those dependencies to the test variant

Comment: @UserOne I've tried `androidTestImplementation` and `kaptAndroidTest` but it hasn't helped

Comment: @StavroXhardha I use own scopes, but I think it is not an issue. As I mentioned in additional info, it works when I copy this class to src dir

Comment: You want your test component for instrumented test not local so, i had a similar issue in local unit test and this post helped Me https://stackoverflow.com/a/45603080/9884320

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `kapt(name: 'processor')`  into `kapt project(':processor')`

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work :/ I get the same error